# Crash in Firebase, no clue

Tags: android, firebase, sqlite, flurry

My project itself does not have database-related code. It may be that my code logic has caused some problems with third-party SDKs. Hope to help me analyze it.

I try to analyze the error, maybe it is related to RBI in Google Firebase or Flurry

```
Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
cannot rollback - no transaction is active (code 1)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute (SQLiteConnection.java)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute (SQLiteConnection.java:555)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransactionUnchecked (SQLiteSession.java:439)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction (SQLiteSession.java:401)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction (SQLiteDatabase.java:524)
androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.endTransaction (FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:90)
androidx.work.impl.WorkDatabase$1.onOpen (WorkDatabase.java:131)
androidx.work.impl.WorkDatabase_Impl$1.onOpen (WorkDatabase_Impl.java:91)
androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onOpen (RoomOpenHelper.java:120)
androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onOpen (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:142)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:266)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:92)
androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:53)
androidx.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction (RoomDatabase.java:328)
androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.cleanUp (ForceStopRunnable.java:135)
androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run (ForceStopRunnable.java:79)
androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run (SerialExecutor.java:91)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: The error message states this is from `androidx.work`, also known as WorkManager, so this is something you should [file an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906) for if you're not already using the latest version of WorkManager.

Comment: The code related to WorkManager in my project has been commented out. Will this problem still occur?

Comment: You'd have to call [`cancelAllWork()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager#cancelAllWork()) to actually clean up any pre-existing work you had scheduled.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have the same issue happen in Samsung Galaxy S10. Any idea?

Comment: Seems most of the problems occur in Samsung phones

Comment: I have the same crash on android 7.1.1, did you find any solution? at least some clue what is this?